# Deriving a function based on its properties

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a function $\Lambda(t)$ for any $t>0$. This function has the following three properties:

1. $\Lambda(t)$ is differentiable.
2. $\Lambda(t)$ is strictly increasing.
3. $\Lambda(T) = \Lambda(T+S) - \Lambda(S)$ for any $T,S>0$.

It is stated that the function has the form $\Lambda(t) = \lambda t$, but how can I formally derive this from the above three properties. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try proving these properties first, by giving $S$ and $T$ various values:
$$\Lambda(0)=0$$
$$\Lambda(2t) = 2\Lambda(t)$$
$$\Lambda(nt) = n\Lambda(t)$$
$$\Lambda(m/n)=m/n\Lambda(1)$$

This should give linearity on $\mathbf{Q}_+$.

To expand linearity to $\mathbf{R}_+$, based on monotonicity only, see [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Monotone_Additive_Function_is_Linear) (using density of the set of rationals in the set of real numbers and [Peak Point lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Peak_Point_Lemma) and [Squeeze theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Squeeze_Theorem/Sequences/Real_Numbers)).

See also [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) for more.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(t) > 0 \rightarrow \Lambda(t) = C t + u$

$\Lambda(S+T) = \Lambda(S) + \Lambda(T) \rightarrow u=0$

Hence

$\Lambda(t) = Ct$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f (x)$ be such a function.From the second property we get,
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
**Step 1** Differentiate partially w.r.t. $x$,
$$f'(x+y)=f'(x)$$
**Step 2** Put  $x=0$,
$$f'(y)=f'(0)=constant$$
**Step 3** This is an Ordinary Differential Equation which gives,
$$f(y)=f'(0)y+C$$
Since $C=0$ (as $f(0)=0$), we get,
$$f(y)=\lambda y$$
Where $\lambda>0$ (from the first property)

Comment: Why is it differentiable?

Comment: @ir7 I was just looking for a differentiable function that has these properties.

Comment: Good try. But  the only property given, besides additivity, is monotonicity.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: it is differentiable. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much